P&L Decomposition Expired Trades
If a trade exists yesterday (T-1) and not today (T) owing to maturity at T, how do you account for the change in P&L between T-1 and T? I think it should be under Theta but are there any cases where you would want to ignore this P&L for a trade maturing today altogether?

Think of it like a swabian housewife. If you own a bond that pays you a coupon tomorrow and run a theta on that what is hidden in all that theta? How would you compare that theta with one that you see on a "normal" day with no coupon nearby? In short: what "is" theta and what it should be is up to you. Know your weapon.

This is actually tricky sometimes. I don't have a perfect answer. In my opinion, accounting practices don't quite describe what happens operationally.
As an example, never mind derivatives, suppose you own a bond that matures on day $T$. If it hasn't defaulted, then accountants say, derecognize the bond asset, pretend that you received a cash flow on day $T$, and are immediately free to spend it. In reality, you may get the cash flow a few days later, and might run into problems if you try to spend it before you operationally receive it.
Almost always, at time $T$, you know whether you will get the cash flow. If the bond issuer hasn't signaled that they're defaulting, then the observable dirty price of the maturing bond will equal the cash flow, so the fair value of the bond asset that you de-recognize will be offset by the cash flow that you recognize (although, as I said, it may come some days after you recognize it), so the net P&L should be close to 0.
If, even on maturity day $T$ there hasn't been an official default, but there are doubts about the cash flow happening, so the bond is trading below face value, then you still de-recognize the bond at its observable fair value - below its face value - and recognize the cash flow, so the net P&L is positive, and if the cash flow comes, it does so as a pleasant surprise. And if the cash flow doesn't come, then you de-recognize the cash flow and re-recognize the defaulted bond. You may sometimes see the not yet defaulted, and supposedly matured, credit-risky bond trading below its face value in the secondary market. See Evergrande for an example of default after $T$.
